# How to use Hikari pool connection in spark dataset jdbc

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, dataset, connection-pooling, hikaricp

Is there any way to read database oracle with **spark** implementing a pool of connection with hikari datasource?

I'm using java

```java
 // How to execute the query below using a pool of connection?

 Dataset<Row> dataset = this.sparkSession.read()
     .option("jdbc")
     .option("url",url_database)
     .option("user",user)
     .option("password",password)
     .option("query","select....")
     .load();
```

How to pass implementation of retrieve connection from datasource when executing query?